# How do I consume an asynchronous response twice

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for best nodeJS practice to consume the result of an asynchronous operation in two places.

I currently have the following pseudo-code

```
async function doSomething() {
  const something = await fetchSomething();
  console.log("something", something); // (A)
}
function fetchSomething() {
   const promise = fetch("http://example.com/something");
   /* new code to update something will live here (B) */
   return promise;
}
```

So far so good

I now need to do make a change to update `something` within `fetchSomething()` at the line `new code will live here`. The new code will be something like `something.timestamp = new Date();`

How can I access `something` within `fetchSomething()` and be sure that the update I make to something at (B) occurs before I log something at (A).

Comment: `return fetch(...).then(() => /* new code to update something will live here */)`? Or use `async` again and `await fetch(...)`. It's not clear what you think needs to be consumed twice.

Comment: _"How can I access `something` within `fetchSomething()`"_ - `fetchSomething()` is the one that returns the content of `something` o.O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your `fetchSomething` to also be `async`:

```js
async function doSomething() {
  const something = await fetchSomething();
  console.log("something", something); // (A)
}

async function fetchSomething() {
    const something = await fetch("http://example.com/something");
    /* new code to update something will live here (B) */
    something.someOtherThing = 'updated something!';
    return something;
}
```

Every `async` function returns a `Promise` so you can just `await` it again.

Comment: in your example, fetchSomething is not returning a promise, it's returning my `something` object. Is that OK? My understanding is that only functions that return promises may be awaited.

Comment: `async` functions implicitly wrap their return values within `Promise`s so that they may be awaited.